# Can't connect to home WiFi - DHCP problem?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, wlan, wicd

I am using wicd for wifi connections. Everything worked fine, but now I suddenly can't connect to my home network anymore. While troubleshooting I tried to set up a hotspot from my Smartphone which connects just fine and gives me internet Access. Could it be a problem with DHCP? I'm attaching a part of my wicd.log file.

`2016/02/08 13:21:37 :: Connecting to wireless network asd23
2016/02/08 13:21:37 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2016/02/08 13:21:37 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: Putting interface down
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: Releasing DHCP leases...
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2016/02/08 13:21:39 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2016/02/08 13:21:40 :: Setting false IP...
2016/02/08 13:21:40 :: Stopping wpa_supplicant
2016/02/08 13:21:40 :: Flushing the routing table...
2016/02/08 13:21:40 :: Putting interface up...
2016/02/08 13:21:42 :: Generating psk...
2016/02/08 13:21:42 :: Attempting to authenticate...
2016/02/08 13:22:17 :: wpa_supplicant authentication may have failed.
2016/02/08 13:22:17 :: connect result is failed
2016/02/08 13:22:17 :: exiting connection thread
2016/02/08 13:22:18 :: Sending connection attempt result bad_pass
2016/02/08 13:22:18 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2016/02/08 13:22:18 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2016/02/08 13:22:19 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2016/02/08 13:22:19 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better`

Even though it says "authentication may have failed", I am pretty sure that my password is correct.

All the trouble started when I had connection issues with my VPN and tried to manually set a DNS Server in /etc/resolv.conf

If you need additional information, just tell me.

Kind regards,
Samy

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I am using Debian 8 with xfce. From what I can tell Network manager is not installed. Lspci says the following: `03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)`

Comment: Tell us how `wpa_supplicant` gets started (like from systemd) and with what flags. Give the output of: `ps a -e | grep wpa_supplicant`

Comment: `7345 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant` is the output. I'm not really sure how it is started to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Remove wicd and wpa_supplicant

Reinstall wpa_supplicant

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Add Source "non-free" in your file /etc/apt/sources.list , for example:

```
# Debian 8 "Jessie"
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update the list of available packages and install the package

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Load module

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

Configure WPA2

```
 nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Setup wlan0 with the SSID and PSK as follows:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid YOUR-SSID-HERE
wpa-psk YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE
```

bring up wlan0:

```
ifup wlan0
```

Restart the networking service using any one of the following method:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your tutorial. Unfortunately whenever I try to connect to a website it fails. When trying to ping a server the following happens: `From 192.168.2.123 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable` (I'm trying to ping 5.44.XX.XX)

Comment: Verify your router and firewall maybe they are configured to block icmp packets

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. I can ping the IP with my computer but not on my laptop (the one with the connection issues). And I'm able to ping it on my laptop when the lan cable is plugged in.